# dkim=softfail with mail() but not with phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, dkim

I have a server that runs a mailing software. This software uses phpmailer.
If I send out an email through this software I have no problem, I get `SPF=PASS` as well as `DKIM=PASS`.

However, when I try to use a regular PHP file that just uses `mail()`, I get the email with a `dkim=softfail (fail, body has been altered) header.i=@example.com` error. Below are the specifics.

I checked online for hours now, but all I found were links to the RFC specifications, saying that this problem is caused by such things as "Lines longer than 990 bytes" or "Malformated line endings" (both of which do not apply here, as I use `chunk_split()`).

What could cause this problem with DKIM in my code? Is there another RFC spec that I am overlooking?

```
**PHP script I use:**

//build array with headers
$header = array();
$boundary = md5(uniqid(rand()));
$header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$header[] = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary = $boundary";
$header[] = "From: Me <me@example.com>";

// get html version
ob_start();
include('html.php');
$Html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// get TXT version
ob_start();
include('txt.php');
$Txt = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Build final message body
// TXT part of message
$body = "--$boundary\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($Txt));

// HTML part of message
$body .= "--$boundary\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($Html));
$body .= "--$boundary--";

// sent email
$isMailed = mail("me@example.com","=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=",$body, implode("\n", $header));
```

EDIT: to help resolve this, here is a sample Email Header that I get with the above script:

```
Return-Path: <apache@example.com>
Delivered-To: me@example.com
Received: from localhost (mx1.example.com [127.0.0.1])
    by mx1.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4E50FBF31F
    for <me@example.com>; Tue, 16 Dec 2014 16:54:43 +0100 (CET)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at mx1.example.com
Authentication-Results: mx1.example.com (amavisd-new);
    dkim=softfail (fail, body has been altered) header.i=@example.com
Received: from mx1.example.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (mx1.example.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id o8MXZhIlf1tF for <me@example.com>;
    Tue, 16 Dec 2014 16:54:42 +0100 (CET)
Received: from example.com (example.com [123.23.45.67])
    by mx1.example.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 92A21AF218
    for <me@example.com>; Tue, 16 Dec 2014 16:54:41 +0100 (CET)
Received: from localhost (mailsvr [127.0.0.1])
    by example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 895B51018227
    for <me@example.com>; Tue, 16 Dec 2014 16:56:23 +0100 (CET)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at example.com
Received: from example.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (mailsvr.example.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with LMTP id gm+3YJEGgEc7 for <me@example.com>;
    Tue, 16 Dec 2014 16:56:22 +0100 (CET)
Received: by example.com (Postfix, from userid 47)
    id A973B317802E; Tue, 16 Dec 2014 16:56:20 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=example.com;
    s=default; t=1418745380;
    bh=wL3reSbwXm4SPw5A8n9RooRKg+7j0rkM5+iBCFG51XI=;
    h=To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:From:Message-Id:Date;
    b=BALRnjP3rx8LcYUxvrLBSASiZyFgA5ckTvGHoKF4V+o8JOLtLTmpmPQS91ohHIwOq
     UFRhv6qJl9ObvFWl0c6QyVthGjCz2+2vB6RkMXQxzJgwxPIe6X51iIEDxA4Y3EYs+x
     0DxmjMTt5tNKNBrjvEtZiEolkfbua8cearxA/Q3M=
To: me@example.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?dGVzdA==?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary = 47eacbbcbff31a13d0894e4f9ac0450b
From: Me <me@example.com>
Message-Id: <20141216155620.A972B387802D@example.com>
Date: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 16:56:20 +0100 (CET)

--47eacbbcbff31a13d0894e4f9ac0450b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

dGVzdA==
--47eacbbcbff31a13d0894e4f9ac0450b
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PC9oZWFkPg0KPGJvZHk+DQo8cD50ZXN0PC9wPg0KPC9ib2R5Pg0KPC9odG1s
Pg==
--47eacbbcbff31a13d0894e4f9ac0450b--
```

Comment: This code evidently isn't doing DKIM signing - so what is?

Comment: You shouldn't be building mime emails manually anyways. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, which'll make most of your code redundant.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, might be true. However, the question here is why my script causes a `dkim=softfail`. I just tested a simple `mail("me@example.com","test","test");` and the email arrives with a PASS. So it must be in the above script that something causes a softfail, as the PHP `mail()` function is not itself creating the problem. My guess is that it has something to do with the format, just as is pointed out in different online answers, except that I can't figure out what as I am following those RFC rules that have been pointed out (as mentioned in my post).

Answer (score 0):

What is your Server? what type of mail server are you using?

Anyone who is still running dkim-milter can swap over to OpenDKIM
in a matter of minutes - keeping your existing keys, DNS settings,
etc.

If you're running CentOS 6 for example, if you have EPEL enabled you
can just do `"yum install opendkim"` and it will install the latest
release version of OpenDKIM with the most common default
configuration, including a set of default keys for your server. The
opendkim package is available in the stable repos for Fedora 14-17 and
EL 5-6.

Second method of troubleshooting: 
 if you're using \n for newline (example end of header line). But you have to use \r\n. This solved it for me!

Comment: Re second method: If I try to send the message using `\r\n`, I get an error that says CR character is not allowed in header.